# CSS styling HTML5 select, input

Tags: css, html, input, stylesheet

I'm pretty new to web stuff.
I'm working on a website using the new HTML5 tags and am having problems with uniformity between all the input fields.

Here is a snippet of the HTML code.

```css
/*======== Styling for the article section */

article {
  font: 10pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Left margin should match neighboring column full width */
}


/*Form overall section*/

form {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  clear: left;
}


/*Form text box sections*/

input,
select {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div>
      <div>
        Payed to:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Payed to" value="Jim's Foodliner">
      </div>

      <div>
        <br> Amount:
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="Amount" value="1">
      </div>

      <div>
        <br>Date:<br>
        <input type="date" name="date">
      </div>

      <div>
        <br>Time:<br>
        <input type="time" name="time">
      </div>

      <div>
        <br>Category<br>
        <div>
          <select name="Category">
            <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
            <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
            <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
            <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <br><br>Billable
        <input type="checkbox" name="Billable" value="Billable">
      </div>

      <div>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</article>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result where you can see that the boxes are a different **heights**. 
It's in Google Chrome btw.
[GoogleChrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ9fP.png)

I'm just trying to get uniformity among the box content **height**.  The padding and margins are all the same just not the inside contents.
I'm pretty new at css, so any weblinks or tutorials that go into more detail on the new html5 tags would be great.
Thanks!

Here are 2 more screenshot to explain the differences between the box heights using chrome developer tools.
[This picture shows the height of the date field in the dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DW8r.png)
[This picture shows the height of the Select/category field in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HMf4.png)

Comment: You can see bootstrap tutorial to learn styling https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/default.asp

Comment: I'm working with CSS without bootstrap first.

Comment: You can check this https://www.csstutorial.net/

Answer (score 0):

use missing `width:100%` on input and select tag

```
article,form  {
 display:block;
}
input,
select {
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make them all the same height.

Answer (score 0):

**Add width:100% to your css code or it can be in percentage,cm or px**

You can decide width size based on your requirement. If you are new to this you can try bootstrap form which are attractive and responsive in mobile view also.Learn more at: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Comment: I already know how to do width.  I'm focusing on the heights.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found my answer on this site.  Thanks all!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms